# Data is not inserting in SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm not able to insert data into a SQL Server using a stored procedure from C# - please help.

```
string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("AddFromExcel", sqlConnection))
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;

    try
    {
      sqlConnection.Open();

      SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();

      for (int i = 0; i < dtExport.Rows.Count ; i++)
      {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter1.ParameterName = "@FamilyName";
        parameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        var value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Family"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilyName", value);

        SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter2.ParameterName = "@ExecutionName";
        parameter2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter2.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Execution"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExecutionName", value);

        SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter3.ParameterName = "@VariantCode";
        parameter3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter3.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["VariantCode"]); //this is column name in Excel
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VariantCode", value);

        SqlParameter parameter4 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter4.ParameterName = "@FamilyDenomination";
        parameter4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter4.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Family Denomination"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilyDenomination", value);

        SqlParameter parameter5 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter4.ParameterName = "@ExcecutionDenomination";
        parameter4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter4.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Execution Denomination"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExcecutionDenomination", value);

        SqlParameter parameter6 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter4.ParameterName = "@ReleasDatestring";
        parameter4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter4.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Release Date"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReleasDatestring", value);

        SqlParameter parameter7 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter7.ParameterName = "@Validfromstring";
        parameter7.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter7.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Valid From"]);
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter7 );

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
     }
     catch (SqlCeException ex)
     {
         string w = ex.Message.ToString();
         //MessageBox.Show("Error",
         //    "Error in Write to .: "
         //    + ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Here stored procedure is working fine, even I am not getting any error while running the program. 
But data is not getting inserted

Comment: You're not really doing anything in the catch block. Can you comment out the try/catch to see if you're getting any exceptions?

Comment: no, still I am not getting any exception and even data is also not getting inserted

Comment: Check your parameter definition. You have declare parameter 5, 6 & 7 but in the definition it is still using parameter4. Please correct the code.

Comment: You are passing the Value for all parameters as **value** only i.e **var value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Family"]);** correct it

Comment: Check your code before posting your (Copy/Paste)code itself contain so many bugs

Comment: By the way, Rajesh your suggestion worked, I was using same value variable all the time.Now I changed and it worked

Comment: @chiuank Good it worked but I prefer not to declare somany parameters adding Parameter name to it and adding value to it Instead you can do it all in a single code like `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parameter_Name", value);`

Comment: even better, use http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/ to do it for you ...

Answer (score 1):

Use `command.Parameters.Add(Parameter_Name)` in your code like

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtExport.Rows.Count ; i++)
{

  command.Parameters.Clear();
  SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter();
  parameter1.ParameterName = "@FamilyName";
  parameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
  parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  parameter1.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Family"]);
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);


  SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter();
  parameter2.ParameterName = "@ExecutionName";
  parameter2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
  parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  parameter2.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Execution"]);
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

  SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter();
  parameter3.ParameterName = "@VariantCode";
  parameter3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
  parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
  parameter3.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["VariantCode"]); //this is column name in Excel
  command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);

   SqlParameter parameter4 = new SqlParameter();
   parameter4.ParameterName = "@FamilyDenomination";
   parameter4.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
   parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
   parameter4.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Family Denomination"]);
   command.Parameters.Add(parameter4);

   SqlParameter parameter5 = new SqlParameter();
   parameter5.ParameterName = "@ExcecutionDenomination";
   parameter5.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
   parameter5.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
   parameter5.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Execution Denomination"]);
   command.Parameters.Add(parameter5);


    SqlParameter parameter6 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter6.ParameterName = "@ReleasDatestring";
    parameter6.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    parameter6.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter6.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Release Date"]);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter6);


    SqlParameter parameter7 = new SqlParameter();
    parameter7.ParameterName = "@Validfromstring";
    parameter7.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
    parameter7.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    parameter7.Value = Convert.ToString(dtExport.Rows[i]["Valid From"]);
    command.Parameters.Add(parameter7);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


  }
```